# Nod32 Anti-Virus is blocking Firebase SSL

Tags: ssl, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting my website on Firebase (`*.firebaseapp.com`). I followed the instructions so that I could add my own domain, and use their SSL.

Everything is working, but on my brother's computer, which is running Nod32, the site is blocked. If I turn of the SSL/TLS-protocol check, then the site works again.

Is there anything I can do? The domain to the site is https://tival.se/

Comment: It must be a setting, because on my computer (that also uses Nod) I can access the site fine.

Comment: This was turned on by default on my brothers computer:
[image](http://i.imgur.com/eiY8EYN.jpg)


It says: "Activate controll of SSL/TLS-protocoll", and after turning it off, the site worked again